# ScrollView making Toolbar disappear on Pre-Lollipop Devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-scrollview

On pre-lollipop devices the toolbar is disappeared but if I set the ScrollBar visibility to `gone` then the, toolbar appears. It's working fine on devices running Lollipop or later.

Here is the expected view:

[image]

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:elevation="0.5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="About Desh Travel"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/busInformationActivityScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp">


            <!-- Image for the bus cover-->

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/busCover"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="198dp"
                android:contentDescription="Cover for the Bus"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <!-- Layout for the Bus name and the rating-->

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/busCover"
                android:background="#28000000"
                android:padding="7dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/busName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                    android:text="Desh Travels"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <com.iarcuschin.simpleratingbar.SimpleRatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:srb_borderColor="#f1bc0e"
                    app:srb_fillColor="#e5e917"
                    app:srb_numberOfStars="5"
                    app:srb_rating="3"
                    app:srb_starBackgroundColor="#f7f9d8"
                    app:srb_starBorderWidth="0.5"
                    app:srb_starSize="15dp"
                    app:srb_starsSeparation="2dp"
                    app:srb_stepSize="1" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <!-- Description of the bus-->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/busDescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/busCover"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus non turpis quam. Sed at sagittis felis. Maecenas blandit vestibulum lorem, quis efficitur diam tempus in."
                android:textColor="#3E3E3E"
                android:textSize="12.5sp" />

            <!--Separator-->

            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewSeparator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/busDescription"
                android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

            <!-- Info of the bus-->

            <!-- 1st Para-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/launchedTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/viewSeparator"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:text="Launched"
                android:textColor="#01AA4F"
                android:textSize="13.5sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totalBusTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/viewSeparator"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
                android:text="Total Bus"
                android:textColor="#01AA4F"
                android:textSize="13.5sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/acBusTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/viewSeparator"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:text="AC Bus"
                android:textColor="#01AA4F"
                android:textSize="13.5sp" />

            <!--1st Info Para-->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/launched"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/launchedTitle"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/launchedTitle"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/launchedTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="2009"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12.5sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totalBus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/totalBusTitle"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/totalBusTitle"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/totalBusTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="50"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12.5sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/acBus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/acBusTitle"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/acBusTitle"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/acBusTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="24"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12.5sp" />

            <!-- 2nd Para-->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nonACBusTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/launched"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/launched"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/launched"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="Non AC Bus"
                android:textColor="#01AA4F"
                android:textSize="13.5sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/busRatingTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/totalBus"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/totalBus"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/totalBus"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="Rating"
                android:textColor="#01AA4F"
                android:textSize="13.5sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eTicketTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/acBus"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/acBus"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/acBus"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="eTicket"
                android:textColor="#01AA4F"
                android:textSize="13.5sp" />

            <!-- 2nd Info Para-->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nonACBus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/nonACBusTitle"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/nonACBusTitle"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/nonACBusTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="26"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12.5sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/busRating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/busRatingTitle"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/busRatingTitle"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/busRatingTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="Rate"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12.5sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eTicket"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/eTicketTitle"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/eTicketTitle"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/eTicketTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="Yes"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12.5sp" />

            <!-- Counter List Button-->

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/counterListButton"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/busRating"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                android:background="#00D463"
                android:paddingLeft="22dp"
                android:paddingRight="22dp"
                android:text="Counter List"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/firstImage"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/counterListButton"
                android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/secondImage"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/secondImage"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/counterListButton"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thirdImage"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/counterListButton"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/secondImage"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fourthImage"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/firstImage"
                android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fifthImage"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fifthImage"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/firstImage"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sixthImage"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/firstImage"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fifthImage"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I will advice to use a Linear Layout as main layout where orientation=vertical will solve your problem.

Comment: try adding `fillviewport = "true"` for the scrollview...in layout xml

Comment: @Er.TysonSubba, I don't want to use Linear Layout because that will make the ScrollView below the toolbar, but I want the toolbar at the top and the scrollview behind it

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 that didn't help :(

Comment: You need to use a collapsing toolbar layout for your requirement according to your image post.

Comment: Actually no, I just want the toolbar to stay at the top and I use an onScrollListener to change the color of the toolbar. Ferdous Ahamed's answer solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

Put your `Toolbar` layout below `ScrollView`.

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/busInformationActivityScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp">

            <!-- Image for the bus cover-->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/busCover"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="198dp"
                android:contentDescription="Cover for the Bus"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <!-- Layout for the Bus name and the rating-->

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/busCover"
                android:background="#28000000"
                android:padding="7dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/busName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                    android:text="Desh Travels"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <com.iarcuschin.simpleratingbar.SimpleRatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:srb_borderColor="#f1bc0e"
                    app:srb_fillColor="#e5e917"
                    app:srb_numberOfStars="5"
                    app:srb_rating="3"
                    app:srb_starBackgroundColor="#f7f9d8"
                    app:srb_starBorderWidth="0.5"
                    app:srb_starSize="15dp"
                    app:srb_starsSeparation="2dp"
                    app:srb_stepSize="1" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <!-- Description of the bus-->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/busDescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/busCover"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus non turpis quam. Sed at sagittis felis. Maecenas blandit vestibulum lorem, quis efficitur diam tempus in."
                android:textColor="#3E3E3E"
                android:textSize="12.5sp" />

            <!--Separator-->

            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewSeparator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/busDescription"
                android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

            <!-- Info of the bus-->

            <!-- 1st Para-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/launchedTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/viewSeparator"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:text="Launched"
                android:textColor="#01AA4F"
                android:textSize="13.5sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totalBusTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/viewSeparator"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
                android:text="Total Bus"
                android:textColor="#01AA4F"
                android:textSize="13.5sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/acBusTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/viewSeparator"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:text="AC Bus"
                android:textColor="#01AA4F"
                android:textSize="13.5sp" />

            <!--1st Info Para-->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/launched"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/launchedTitle"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/launchedTitle"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/launchedTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="2009"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12.5sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totalBus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/totalBusTitle"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/totalBusTitle"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/totalBusTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="50"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12.5sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/acBus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/acBusTitle"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/acBusTitle"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/acBusTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="24"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12.5sp" />

            <!-- 2nd Para-->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nonACBusTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/launched"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/launched"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/launched"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="Non AC Bus"
                android:textColor="#01AA4F"
                android:textSize="13.5sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/busRatingTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/totalBus"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/totalBus"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/totalBus"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="Rating"
                android:textColor="#01AA4F"
                android:textSize="13.5sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eTicketTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/acBus"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/acBus"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/acBus"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="eTicket"
                android:textColor="#01AA4F"
                android:textSize="13.5sp" />

            <!-- 2nd Info Para-->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nonACBus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/nonACBusTitle"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/nonACBusTitle"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/nonACBusTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="26"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12.5sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/busRating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/busRatingTitle"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/busRatingTitle"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/busRatingTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="Rate"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12.5sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eTicket"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/eTicketTitle"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/eTicketTitle"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/eTicketTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="Yes"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12.5sp" />

            <!-- Counter List Button-->

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/counterListButton"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/busRating"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                android:background="#00D463"
                android:paddingLeft="22dp"
                android:paddingRight="22dp"
                android:text="Counter List"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/firstImage"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/counterListButton"
                android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/secondImage"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/secondImage"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/counterListButton"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thirdImage"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/counterListButton"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/secondImage"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fourthImage"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/firstImage"
                android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fifthImage"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fifthImage"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/firstImage"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sixthImage"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/firstImage"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fifthImage"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:elevation="0.5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="About Desh Travel"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**FYI,** You can also achieve this behavior by using `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, `NestedScrollView` and `CoordinatorLayout`.

**Here are some good tutorials:**

https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/
http://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout

Hope this will help~

Comment: That would make the ScrollView below the toolbar which I don't want, this is what I want, https://imghost.io/images/2017/04/19/Screenshot_1492593085.md.png This is what I get when set layout_below https://imghost.io/images/2017/04/19/Screenshot_1492593062.md.png

Comment: If my answer seems useful, dont forget to give an up-vote. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

add in *ScrollView*

```
android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
```

**Edit**

You can use `AppBarLayout` with `CoordinatorLayout` for different scrolling behaviour   see [sample](http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator)

Comment: That would make the ScrollView below the toolbar which I don't want,
this is what I want, https://imghost.io/images/2017/04/19/Screenshot_1492593085.md.png
This is what I get when set layout_below
https://imghost.io/images/2017/04/19/Screenshot_1492593062.md.png

Comment: then what do you want?. You havn't clarified in question

Comment: Actually no, I just want the toolbar to stay at the top and I use an onScrollListener to change the color of the toolbar. Ferdous Ahamed's answer solved it